# Android Play-store behavior on app download

Tags: android, google-play

I was just curious to know few basic behavior of the google play-store.
Tried to find the answers of below questions:

1) If my phone network is switched from cellular to WI-FI while i am downloading an app from the play- 
   store. How google manages the connection as it resumes the download from where it stopped, because as 
   far as i know the IP address will change and TCP connection restarts the session.

2) What are the detailed steps involved right from requesting for an app from play-store till it is 
   installed in our device. I mean what are the factors of the device google crosschecks, for instance,
   if the minimum version of the app is 7.0 and i have a device of 6.0, will the .apk gets downloaded and 
   then the version is verified or it is verified before the download starts.

Couldn't able to find a document on these. Please share if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 2)
The Play Store won't offer you an app for download if your phone doesn't meet it's requirements. This means you won't be able to download the app via the play store if:

- Your phone doesn't meet the required minimum android version
- Your phone doesn't support one of the features that are marked with `uses-feature required="true"` in the manifest ([see reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#market-feature-filtering))

  - e.g. NFC, camera
- The vendor explicitly excluded your phone from the list of supported devices

  - e.g. some Samsung apps are only available for Samsung smartphones, like [Gear 360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.gear360manager) app. Some games are only available for Nvidia Shield like [Half Life 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nvidia.valvesoftware.halflife2)
- The vendor doesn't release the app in your region

Comment: You mean to say that android play-store have all the spec information of my device? and it filters out my application bucket on play-store based on my device spec?

Comment: That is correct. You can try this out by opening the app links above. If your device is not supported, you won't find this apps at all in the play store search from your phone.It will be only visible on the play store website. If you are logged in, you will see the message "This app is not compatible with any of your devices".

Comment: So if i have a feature in my .apk which requires minimum of android version 7. According to the above nuance, my .apk will not be visible to all the devices below android 7. So if i want my .apk to be used on devices below android 7 also, do i need to exclude that particular feature and make another .apk for all the devices below android 7?

Comment: or else i think we can handle it on run-time in a single .apk by adding the uses-permission programmatically before the user tries to use that feature.

Comment: You can still set a lower minsdk version and check programatically if the user's phone has at least API level 24. This way, it is visible to lower-version phones and users with API level 24 can use your feature.

A more modern approach would be the usage of dynamic-features. They allow you to offer the specific package which requires a feature only for phones that actually support it. This way, users don't need to download the part of the App which they can't use anyway. See conditional delivery for further reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/conditional-delivery